# How to compare two string with consecutive set character in RegEx using C#

Tags: c#, regex

First string is

> string str1 ="aaa sdf xxx fgd bbb efg rrr";

second string

> string str2 ="ddd qwe ccc fgd eee ehj";

What should be the RegEx pattern ,Which say str1 and str2 are
identical by pattern.

```
string pattern = "---------"; 

if(Regex.Match(str1 , pattern).Success== Regex.Match(str2 , pattern).Success)
{
     return true;
}
```

> if string like this

`string str1 = "afa fff fss fgd bfb efg rrr";`

`string str2 = "sdf qwe cfc fgd ege ehj";`

> the code should return false

Comment: This is not really a thing to use regex for. Comparing two strings is a common operation supported natively in any programming language. Did I miss your point here?

Comment: Can you post a list of inputs and expected results, otherwise it's hard to see what you need. I might be way off track here but it looks like you want to check the *patterns* are the same - i.e. "aaa sdf" is equal to "ddd qwe" because the interval between the characters on the keyboard is the same...? Something like that?

Comment: yes Charleh you,exactly the same what u understand

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression would be:

```
[a-z\ ]*
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following:**

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1
```

**Referance:**

http://icfun.blogspot.in/2008/07/regex-to-match-same-consecutive.html

Hope Its Helpful.

Comment: this pattern should not return true for this
 `string str3 = "afa fff fss fgd bfb efg rrr";`
        `string str4 = "sdf qwe cfc fgd ege ehj";`

Comment: It will return true for this condition. try reverse condition by adding (!) not before condition matching

Comment: > Hi,i tried 

`public static bool CompareRegExIntQuest(string first,string second)'


`        {`

`           bool issome = false;`

`            string pattern = @"^(?!.*(.)\1)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d._-]*$!";`


`            if (Regex.Match(first, pattern).Success == Regex.Match(second, pattern).Success)`

`            {`

`                return true;`

`            }`

`            return issome;`


`        }` 

> but again its returning true is should return false for below string

`string str1 = "afa fff fss fgd bfb efg rrr";`
 
`string str2 = "sdf qwe cfc fgd ege ehj"`

Comment: Hi thanks, its working fine if string is like

            `string str1 = "aaa sdf xxx fgd bbb efg rrr";`
            `string str2 = "ddd qwe ccc fgd eee ehj";`
            `string str3 = "afa fff fss fgd bfb efg rrr";`
            `string str4 = "sdf qwe cfc fgd ege ehj";`

when the combination 

_(str1, str2); True as expected_
_(str3, str4); False as expected_
_(str1, str4); False as expected_

**(str1, str3); True as not expected**

Answer (score 0):

```
var segments1 = str1.Split(' ').Select((str, index) => new { Count = str.Length, Index = index });
var segments2 = str2.Split(' ').Select((str, index) => new { Count = str.Length, Index = index });
bool bIsSamePattern = true;
foreach(var segment in segments1)
{
  var segment2 = segments2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Index == segment.Index);
  if (segment2 == null)
    break;
  bIsSamePattern = segment2.Count == segment.Count;
}
```

You don't need to use `Regex` if that would be easier for you.

Comment: Hi Luke this code should not return true for this 
string str3 = "afa fff fss fgd bfb efg rrr";
string str4 = "sdf qwe cfc fgd ege ehj";